# How to read a JSON value in Codename One that does not come from a StreamReader

Tags: codenameone

I have read through the CN1 documentation to try and work with JSON, but all the JSON examples I can see are reading the values from a StreamReader. What if my JSON value is a String variable and not a value from a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read that using `CharArrayReader`. Notice you should use the version from `com.codename1.io` and not the one from the java package.

```
Reader r = new CharArrayReader(str.toCharArray());
```